# htaccess redirecting multiple domains, https and http, www and non-www, all to one https domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have three different domains, and I want to make sure that all domains redirect to the one domain.

I want to make sure all cases are covered: if the user types http or https, if they include www or not.

This create 12 different possibilities...

```
http://www.domain1.co.uk
https://www.domain1.co.uk
http://domain1.co.uk
https://domain1.co.uk

http://www.domain2.uk
https://www.domain2.uk
http://domain2.uk
https://domain2.uk

http://www.domain3.co.uk
https://www.domain3.co.uk
http://domain3.co.uk
https://domain3.co.uk
```

And I need all of these to redirect to:

```
https://www.domain3.co.uk
```

I have set up my .htaccess file in the way I thought should work with most variations, and I have researched this on Google and SO, and this looked to me to be the best solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain3\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain3.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But this covers only 11 of these variations.

With this htaccess file, if I visit the URL:

```
http://www.domain3.co.uk
```

It does not redirect.

All other variations redirect as required.

How can I change my htaccess file so that all 12 possible variations are covered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this single rule with a `[OR]` clause:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain3\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain3.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: @anubhava domain3 is the goal not doamin2. Anyway you can try it on this real example. https://www.vibratape.de is the main domain. if you try https://www.vibratape.com it does not work.

Comment: I mistyped actually. It was supposed to be `domain3`. But as you can see rule is straight forward redirect to `www.domain3.co.uk` if you come from a different domain. Having said that if it is not working for you due to your local config/code issue then you may post a new question with all details so that I can look at it.

Comment: @anubhava thanks... here is the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757719/htaccess-how-to-redirecting-multiple-domains-in-all-variations-to-one-domain-wit