# htaccess how to redirecting multiple domains in all variations to one domain with https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.vibratape\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.vibratape.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

There are this domain...

- vibra-tape.de
- vibra-tape.com
- vibratape.com
- vibratape.de (this is the goal domain)

Every combination work except one. If you enter a none goal domain with https... exmpl.

```
https://www.vibratape.com
```

Comment: `https://www.vibratape.com/` doesn't even open in browser due to `ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT` error though `http://www.vibratape.com/` does open.

Comment: I guess because the ssl certificate is valid for the main domain only. Is there a way to avoid https if the domain is not vibratape.de?

Comment: No that cannot be done in rewrite rules because SSL handshake happens before mod_rewrite is invoked. To be able to redirect `https://www.vibratape.com` to `https://www.vibratape.de` you need a valid SSL cert for `https://www.vibratape.com`

Comment: Ok thanks... its quite unrealistic that someone type a secondary domain with https... but its still unsatisfactory. Who would buy an certificate for a secondary domain?